# ASP.NET Core - Publish on local IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, publish, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core (with .NET Framework) to my pc local IIS Server using Web Deploy feature in Visual Studio 2015.

I've previously created the website through the IIS management console and when I launch the publish, the process runs for a while and the fails with the following error:

```
Web deployment task failed. (The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.)

The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.
Default credentials cannot be supplied for the Basic authentication scheme.
Parameter name: authType
```

How can I resolve this?

Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT**

I was able to publish in [Joe Audette way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931190/asp-net-core-publish-on-local-iis?noredirect=1#comment69073520_40931190) but if I try to open the site the browser show me the IIS default presentation page and if I add */wwwroot* to the url (*http://localhost:2020/wwwroot*) it starts loading but fail with:

[image]

In the event viewer there is the following errors:

```
Nome dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: FrancescoBombardiSite.exe, versione: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x583c58cc
Nome del modulo che ha generato l'errore: KERNELBASE.dll, versione: 10.0.14393.321, timestamp: 0x57f4c4f0
Codice eccezione: 0xe0434352
Offset errore 0x0000000000017788
ID processo che ha generato l'errore: 0x2c24
Ora di avvio dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: 0x01d24ca340117e4e
Percorso dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FrancescoBombardi\FrancescoBombardiSite.exe
Percorso del modulo che ha generato l'errore: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

ID segnalazione: 28d01740-6aa7-4b47-b655-b29b954e647e
Nome completo pacchetto che ha generato l'errore: 
ID applicazione relativo al pacchetto che ha generato l'errore:

and

```
Failed to start process with commandline '"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FrancescoBombardi\FrancescoBombardiSite.exe" .\FrancescoBombardiSite.exe', ErrorCode = '0x80004005'.
```

Moreover, inside logs folder there are more than one log that say:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "aspnet-FrancescoBombardiSite-f583e776-b66c-44ed-9cc9-af235eed1ae0" requested by the login. The login failed.
  Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
     in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
     in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
     in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
     in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
     in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
     in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
     in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
     in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
     in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
     in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
     in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
  ClientConnectionId:d384f84d-2b93-4172-ace7-96b6e52aa1a5
  Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "aspnet-FrancescoBombardiSite-f583e776-b66c-44ed-9cc9-af235eed1ae0" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:d384f84d-2b93-4172-ace7-96b6e52aa1a5
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

Eccezione non gestita: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "aspnet-FrancescoBombardiSite-f583e776-b66c-44ed-9cc9-af235eed1ae0" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   in System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   in System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   in FrancescoBombardiSite.Data.DataInitializer.CreateAdminFunctions() in C:\Code\VisualStudioProjects\BMSoftware\FrancescoBombardiSite\src\FrancescoBombardiSite\Data\DataInitializer.cs:riga 44
   in FrancescoBombardiSite.Data.DataInitializer.<InitializeDataAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Code\VisualStudioProjects\BMSoftware\FrancescoBombardiSite\src\FrancescoBombardiSite\Data\DataInitializer.cs:riga 35
--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove Š stata generata l'eccezione ---
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   in FrancescoBombardiSite.Startup.<Configure>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Code\VisualStudioProjects\BMSoftware\FrancescoBombardiSite\src\FrancescoBombardiSite\Startup.cs:riga 323
--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove Š stata generata l'eccezione ---
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: why not publish to a local file system folder then just copy the files into the deployment folder?

Comment: @JoeAudette please see the edit.

Comment: did you install the aspnet core hosting module for IIS? https://aka.ms/dotnetcore_windowshosting_1_1_0

Comment: your error is about the connection string, I think you need to change from localdb to sqlserver express and use a sql user in the connection string

Comment: @JoeAudette Yes, that was the problem. Thank you. Stupid mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like it could not connect to the database.

I'd guess you need to update your connection string in the published files.